# Log in approvals

Tags: facebook, security, login

I have been locked out of my Facebook account for five days now. The issue is that I can not receive the verification code via text, I have tried sending me issue through the links you have provided but in vain. Kindly help me get back to my account, it is my business point of contact

Comment: which links, who's provided?